# Python getting a variable recognized for GPIO

Tags: python

I'm trying to get an int into my variable for my GPIO pin, but I just don't know how to fit it in.

From the documentation: GPIO "channel must be an integer or list/tuple of integers"

The button_number comes in as a int from an above part code. And part of the code I'm working with looks as follows:

```
button1 = 27
GPIO.setup(button + button_number, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(button + button_number, GPIO.LOW)
```

What I'm hoping to accomplish is adding the int number together with the button "pre-text" and get it recognized as the variable that's saved above.

Running this I get an error:

```
NameError: global name 'button' is not defined
```

I've also tried:

```
GPIO.output("button" + button_number, GPIO.LOW)
```

&

```
pin = "button" + button_number
GPIO.setup(int(pin), GPIO.OUT)
```

I'm running out of idea's. Please help!

Comment: I already answered you in your previous deleted question, have you tried that?

Comment: I realized i didn't ask the question properly and thus deleted it and asked it more clearly. @Caumons, Thank you for your suggestion Caumons, and yes I did try it but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: The answer to this is question is always the same: use a dict. See the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1373185/104349) to the duplicate question (unfortunately some of the other answers give pretty poor advice).